# Ubuntu system corrupt after sudo apt-get install libudev-dev

Tags: ubuntu, corrupt

After I run `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` on my ubuntu machine, the screen turns black and I cannot reboot anymore.

If I try to reboot, I find myself in a command line interface. I don't know how to get back to the normal Ubuntu GUI.

This is now the second time it happens. The first time I did a re-installation of ubuntu, and I hoped this was just an accident but nope..

Anyone who can help me "fix" my ubuntu without needing to re-install?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running from external SSD on Dell XPS 15 (9520)

Thanks,
Jelle

Answer (score 0):

We may encounter the same problem. Linux came into emergent mode after reboot. And home dir couldn't be mount. The log shows that path of the udev-admn is not correct in some service file. We used /bin/udev-admn instead and then it worked.

Maybe the answer is incomplete since we had unintstalled some graphic drivers before.

Answer (score 0):

I've repeatedly had the exact same issue on Ubuntu 22.10 both in VirtualBox and in a Live session while it used to work flawlessly a few weeks ago.

I've checked [the package's changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_251.4-1ubuntu7.1/changelog) and noticed a recent security update from 251.4-ubuntu7 to 251.4-ubuntu7.1.

A potential workaround is to install not the latest but the penultimate version of that package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libudev-dev=251.4-ubuntu7
```

Hope that helps.